Horror movie about two families that wanted to buy a secluded house
I saw a film around 2011 and I forgot the name of the movie. It was about these two families that wanted to buy a secluded house. When they got there, they tried to go back home but the road home was gone. So they stayed there and food appeared everyday. Until people  started getting killed and others appeared to have committed suicide. Then in the end one girl is alive and gets her her tongue cut off.

I believe this is the plot of House Hunting (AKA The Wrong House) with Marc Singer from 2012, where two families move into an abandoned house and discover that they can't leave (though the house keeps providing them with just enough food). They also meet a mysterious and distraught girl whose tongue was cut out. Here is the trailer.
